# Converting updating series of images to video with different durations using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, conversion, concatenation

My program generates images with different frame durations. I want to generate a video of them using ffmpeg simultaneously while new images are generated

I know how to generate a video using `concat` and an input file, but it requires all images to be already generated. Also I know how to work with pipes and `stdin` but it seems it doesn't accept different durations for each input image or I couldn't find the flag/option in documentation or internet.

So my question is how to combine these 2 approaches to generate video from stream of images with different durations?

Best Regards